When I try to perform testing in my knowledge base, the model does not load in amazon bedrock
When I try to perform testing using my knowledge base for RAG in amazon bedrock, when I have to select the model, it keeps loading forever
I tried activating the claude model by antrophic, because I know that is the only model available in amazon bedrock

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
